# Is there a bandwidth efficient way to setup VM on a remote XenServer?

Tags: virtualization, xenserver

Is there a bandwidth efficient way to setup VM (like setting up Linux / Windows from Console) from a remote XenServer?

I am trying to setup Linux/Windows vm from a remote server; however the console is painfully slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used SSH Tunner to get the VNC consoles then adjust the quality to achieve better connection from the VNC Client.

Answer (score 1):

Typically with the console that you'd be using with something like this, you can adjust the quality of what your seeing to match the bandwidth of your connection. I've not used XenServer, but if it's anything like ESXi or Proxmox then you should be able to adjust the settings for lower bandwidth connections.